# how can I write a MIPS assembly code to write a function

Tags: function, assembly, mips, low-level

Hi I've just started learning MIPS codeing and I'm really stuck on this, I want to write a  function called **isCapital**, that tests whether a character **ch** is capitalcase or not?
Please help, Thank you.

Comment: Character are coded in [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) and upper case char have a code >=65. If you provide a [mre], we can try to solve problems that you encounter.

Comment: Almost a duplicate: [What is the idea behind ^= 32, that converts lowercase letters to upper and vice versa?](//stackoverflow.com/q/54536362) and [to converting upper and lower case why we add +32 and -32 pleas explain](//stackoverflow.com/q/34703007)

Comment: All you need is `addiu $v0, $a0, -'A'` / `sltiu $v0, $v0, 26` for a range-check for between `'A'` and `'Z'` (inclusive), using the unsigned compare trick.

Answer (score -2):

```
.data

 lowerCaseChar: .asciiz "Lower case character"
 upperCaseChar: .asciiz "Upper case character"
 notAlphabeticChar: .asciiz "Not alphabetic character "
      char : .byte 'b'  # type a character what you want 
.text
.globl main

 main:

 jal isCapital

 exit:
     li $v0, 10
     syscall
 isCapital:
addi $sp,$sp,-4
sw $ra,0($sp)

lbu $s0,char
sge $t1,$s0,65
sle $t2,$s0,90
and $t3,$t1,$t2
beq $t3,1,upperCase

sge $t1,$s0,97
sle $t2,$s0,122
and $t3,$t1,$t2
beq $t3,1,lowerCase

j notAlphabetic

end:
li $v0,4
syscall

lw $ra,0($sp)
addi $sp,$sp,4
jr $ra


lowerCase:
       la $a0,lowerCaseChar    # system call 4 for print lower case
       j end

upperCase:
       la $a0,upperCaseChar    # system call 4 for print upper case
       j end
notAlphabetic:
       la $a0,notAlphabeticChar
       j end
```

Comment: The logic here is buried under a ton of I/O and useless store/reload.  And you're assuming the character is alphabetic.  Unless I'm missing something, this has false-positives and will report characters like `'='` as upper-case.

Comment: @PeterCordes Do you think is better ? I kept the output result for a better comprehension

Comment: The logic is a bit complicated to use with no comments and no description in text outside of the code block.  I understand it because I already know that the sane options for a range check are `c - 'A' < 26` (unsigned), or `c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'`, but you didn't even use `'A'` instead of `65` or things like that.   (But note that `sge` is a pseudo-instruction.  GCC has to use slt and xori to emulate it if necessary: https://godbolt.org/z/g4reZI.)

Comment: Also, writing a function that only checks a global is a pretty bad example.  Pass it an arg in a register if you want to make it a function that you `jal` to, e.g. with `li $a0, 'b'`!  This is also a bad example of laying out branches: the last case can just fall through instead of reaching a `j` instruction, e.g. putting the `end` block after `notAlphabetic`.  And it's a leaf function so saving/restoring `$ra` is noise.